# RatingControl - capture number of stars clicked from viewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am using RatingControl class (found on gitHub) in my app for recording feedback for 4 criteria(instances). I have to separately capture the number of stars clicked in each instance from the viewController. How can I capture capture the number of stars clicked from viewController and also differentiate which instance has been clicked. I believe i have to use the function ratingButtonTapped from RatingControl class but not sure how to achieve this.

ViewController code snippet below:

```
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var ratingControl1: RatingControl!
  @IBOutlet weak var ratingControl2: RatingControl!
  @IBOutlet weak var ratingControl3: RatingControl!
  @IBOutlet weak var ratingControl4: RatingControl!

  //I want to use some code within ViewController to capture the #stars clicked
```

RatingControl class below:

```
@IBDesignable class RatingControl: UIStackView {

//MARK: Properties

private var ratingButtons = [UIButton]()

var rating = 0 {
    didSet {
        updateButtonSelectionStates()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var starSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 44.0, height: 44.0) {
    didSet {
        setupButtons()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var starCount: Int = 5 {
    didSet {
        setupButtons()
    }
}

//MARK: Initialization

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupButtons()
}

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setupButtons()
}

//MARK: Button Action

func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
    guard let index = ratingButtons.index(of: button) else {
        fatalError("The button, \(button), is not in the ratingButtons array: \(ratingButtons)")
    }

    // Calculate the rating of the selected button
    let selectedRating = index + 1

    if selectedRating == rating {
        // If the selected star represents the current rating, reset the rating to 0.
        rating = 0
    } else {
        // Otherwise set the rating to the selected star
        rating = selectedRating
    }

    print(selectedRating)
}


//MARK: Private Methods

private func setupButtons() {

    // Clear any existing buttons
    for button in ratingButtons {
        removeArrangedSubview(button)
        button.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    ratingButtons.removeAll()

    // Load Button Images
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let filledStar = UIImage(named: "filledStar", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)
    let emptyStar = UIImage(named:"emptyStar", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)
    let highlightedStar = UIImage(named:"highlightedStar", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)

    for index in 0..<starCount {
        // Create the button
        let button = UIButton()

        // Set the button images
        button.setImage(emptyStar, for: .normal)
        button.setImage(filledStar, for: .selected)
        button.setImage(highlightedStar, for: .highlighted)
        button.setImage(highlightedStar, for: [.highlighted, .selected])

        // Add constraints
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: starSize.height).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: starSize.width).isActive = true

        // Set the accessibility label
        button.accessibilityLabel = "Set \(index + 1) star rating"

        // Setup the button action
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Add the button to the stack
        addArrangedSubview(button)

        // Add the new button to the rating button array
        ratingButtons.append(button)
    }

    updateButtonSelectionStates()
}

private func updateButtonSelectionStates() {
    for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerated() {
        // If the index of a button is less than the rating, that button should be selected.
        button.isSelected = index < rating

        // Set accessibility hint and value
        let hintString: String?
        if rating == index + 1 {
            hintString = "Tap to reset the rating to zero."
        } else {
            hintString = nil
        }

        let valueString: String
        switch (rating) {
        case 0:
            valueString = "No rating set."
        case 1:
            valueString = "1 star set."
        default:
            valueString = "\(rating) stars set."
        }

        button.accessibilityHint = hintString
        button.accessibilityValue = valueString
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which repo you are using ? There should be some function or property to access current value of rating provided.

Comment: There is a function ratingButtonTapped within RatingControl class but i don't know how to trap from ViewController class when button is clicked and also how to differentiate which instance button was clicked.

Comment: share repo link here.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should to create protocol `RatingControlDelegate`:

```
@objc protocol RatingControlDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    @objc optional func ratingButtonTapped(_ ratingControl: RatingControl)
}
```

Then add `delegate` var in `RatingControl`:

```
var delegate: RatingControlDelegate?
```

Then add delegate method in the end of `ratingButtonTapped(:_)`:

```
func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
    // ... end of func
    delegate?.ratingButtonTapped?(self)
}
```

In `DetailsViewController` `viewDidLoad(:_)`:

```
ratingControl1.delegate = self
ratingControl2.delegate = self
ratingControl3.delegate = self
ratingControl4.delegate = self
```

And in the implementation of `RatingControlDelegate` in `DetailsViewController` you'll have `ratingControl.rating` variable:

```
func ratingButtonTapped(_ ratingControl: RatingControl) {
    ratingControl.rating // shows your rating

    // detect which instance has been clicked
    switch ratingControl {
    case ratingControl1:

    case ratingControl2:

    // etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used HCSStarRatingView to display star rate fetching in my project 
you can check below link for the same.

It provide me star value by 
(Ex. viwFeedBackStar.value)

https://github.com/hsousa/HCSStarRatingView

I know it is different library as per your implementation but it really works

to fetch star ratting in ios

Answer (score 1):

**No need to make any change in your code.** Just access **current rating value using .rating property.**

So within ViewController class, when you need to access rating value just write

```
print(ratingControl1.rating)
print(ratingControl2.rating)
```

but if you need to access rating value as user tap on any rating control, then modyfy your code with [Aleksandr Zarubin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5901504/aleksandr-zarubin) answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is straightforward and the approach I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use apple recommended rating view controller  "SKStoreReviewController" from StoreKit

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller